# How to get the substring before the last occurrence of a character?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

In oracle I have a string that looks like this:
`\A\B\C\D`

Now I would like to get the substring before the last occurrence of `\`. I don't know how long the string in total will be, as A, B, C and D can differ in length, and the number of `\` might vary as well.
What is the most efficient way to get `\A\B\C\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of `instr` (with -1) and `substr`:

```
with data as (select '\A\B\C\D' str from dual)
select str, substr(str, 1, instr(str, '\', -1)) 
from data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '[^\\]+$', '')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=edf8c609d1842b093189b238e3a435a8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Why would anyone use regular expressions, when a perfectly valid, much more efficient solution using just SUBSTR and INSTR was already visible to all? This is poor advice; -1 from me, because the other answer was available already. Better to remove this answer.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . Fixed.

Comment: lately realised that the last backslash is missing now.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . That is because *I* wouldn't want the backslash if I were doing this.  But that is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: No, OP clearly states \A\B\C\ with a trailing backslash.

Answer (score 0):

A solution through a Regex function might be

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^\\]+$') 
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=58b43f5cc4102cafabfbbbc6dbf69448)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

if it is desired that that last occurrence of the \ character be skipped also, then this might work.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,'(.*)(\.*$)',
                      1,
                      1,
                      NULL,
                      1)
```

this was learned from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63458155/18021603